# PC hard resets when GPU load is high

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply, hardware-failure, gpu

I have a:

- GPU: Sapphire NITRO+ OC RX480
- Mobo: h81m-s (BIOS version :F2)
- CPU: Intel i5-4460
- RAM: Corsair vengeance 8GB DDR3
- PSU: Corsair VS550

Every time I start something graphics intensive the PC restarts. I used DDU and removed all the Intel, Nvidia and AMD drivers and reinstalled it, but the problem persists. I even tried reinstalling Windows.

Event Viewer says:

```
The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could   
be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.
```

PSU voltages from BIOS:

```
+12V  rail 12.0960V
+5V   rail 5.07000V
+3.3V rail 3.38370V
```

Whenever it hard resets, when it reboots display is entirely corrupted until Windows starts. Furmark runs for 1hr but when i start CS:GO it reboots. Rainbow Six Siege and Rocket League runs stable at 150fps. Only some games have this issue CSGO and Mafia 3 until now. I can't figure out if the problem is the PSU, GPU or the motherboard not delivering enough power via the PCI-E slot (total power drawn at load is ~165W). It's not the RAM since it passed the memtest. It's not the temperatures either, since it's never more than 60° C with load.

Comment: Your power supply is only rated at 550 Watts.  That seems pretty low.  It's possible that the power supply is failing when the load gets too high.

Comment: Furmark causes full load and up to 200W but it doesn't crash :/

Comment: I too would initially first point at the PSU, but a few weeks ago I answered another question that was roughly the same as this. PC crashes during graphic intensive situations, but will not crash at all when trying to stress test the PC. The problem was solved by moving the video card to a different PCI-E slot. I had a similar problem before and it took me 2 months to figure it out. i haven't had a single crash since changing PCI-E slots.

Comment: I don't have another PCI slot. This motherboard is pretty old supports only PCI-E 2.0. should I try cleaning the PCI-E slot?